# While with comparison operator

Tags: python

I'm learning Python by myself and have the following issue:

Here's my "checklist":

- Using a while loop to get the user input, `animal_name`, of 4 animals
- Use a counter, `num_animals`, in the while loop condition
- Append the names to a string variable, `all_animals`
- User can exit early by typing "exit" (check; if animal_name is "exit" and break)
- When the loop finishes, print the names of all_animals
- Print "no animals" if animal_name is empty after exiting the loop.

**EDITED**
I wrote the following code, but it doesn't work. What do I need to change, so that every input of an animal will be counted?

```
animal_name = input("Put in 4 animal names in total per time or \"exit\" for break")

num_animals = 0

tot_animals = 4

all_names = ""

while num_animals <= tot_animals:
    print(num_animals, "now")
    num_animals += 1
    all_animals += animal_name + "," # connect the name to all names.

    if animal_name.lower() == ("exit"):
        break

if len(all_animals) == 0: # len is 0, then it's empty
    print("no animals")

print("names of all animals: ", all_animals)
```

***Improved code from @Zhd Zilin***

Comment: "it doesn't work" - how exactly does it not work?

Comment: This would be a good use-case for a list.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you not get the desired output or does it throw an error?

Comment: do you know how to concatenate strings ? using `all_animals = animal_name` you can't concatenate strings. You need at least `+=` for this. But if you want to add `,` then you need more.

Comment: Without knowing your problem, I would do all_animals_list = [] and then in the loop: all_animals_list.append(animal_name)

Answer (score 1):

```
num_animals = 0
tot_animals = 4
all_names = ""
while num_animals <= tot_animals: # will execute 5 times, 0,1,2,3,4...
    # move into loop, everytime it run, it will ask you input
    animal_name = input("Put in 4 animal names in total per time or \"exit\" for break\n") 
    print(num_animals, "now")
    num_animals += 1

    # when input is exit, quit the program
    if animal_name.lower() == "exit":
        break

    all_names += animal_name + "," # Move this line under break, if "exit" input, don't add it to names, connect the name to all names.

if len(all_names) == 0: # len is 0, then it's empty
    print("no animals")

print("names of all animals: ", all_names)
```

update the program, see the comment at the while statement line.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the following output: `Put in 4 animal names in total per time or "exit" for breakhorse, tiger, bird, fish, cow
0 now
1 now
2 now
3 now
4 now
names of all animals:  horse, tiger, bird, fish, cow,horse, tiger, bird, fish, cow,horse, tiger, bird, fish, cow,horse, tiger, bird, fish, cow,horse, tiger, bird, fish, cow,` I have putted in 5 animals, but it is only permitted to put 4 animals, since tot_animals = 4. What do I need to change, so that every input of an animal will be counted?

Comment: Thank you! Everything works, except this one: `if len(all_names) == 0: print("no animals")` I get the following as output: `names of all animals: , , , , `instead of `no animals`

Answer (score 1):

```
num_animals = 0
tot_animals = 4
all_names = ""

while num_animals <= tot_animals:
    # Doing this within the while loop will prompt the user for input
    # each iteration of the loop.
    animal_name = input("Put in 4 animal names in total per time or \"exit\" for break")
    if animal_name.lower() == "exit":
        break

    num_animals += 1
    # This will append the user's input to all_names
    all_names += animal_name + " "

if len(all_names) == 0:
    print("no animals")
else:
    print("names of all animals: ", all_names)
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be able to work.

```
num_animals = 0
tot_animals = 4
all_names = [] # Store the names in a list instead

print("Enter names of 4 animal or type 'exit' to stop.")

while num_animals < tot_animals:
    print("Input an animal name")
    animal_name = input(":")
    if animal_name.lower() == "exit":
        break
    else:
        num_animals += 1
        all_names.append(animal_name) # Use .append() method to element to list

if len(all_names) != 0:
    print("All animals:",tot_animals,all_names)
else:
    print("No animals")
```

Plus make your code clean, Improve the arrangement for easier debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_animals = 4
animal_name = ""
all_animals = str("")

while num_animals > 0:
    animal_name = input("Name an animal: ")
    num_animals -= 1
    if animal_name.lower() == "exit":
        break
    else:
        all_animals = all_animals + " "+ animal_name   #to store the values for all animals

if all_animals == "":
    print("no animals")
else:
    print(all_animals)
```